# How to print the pdf with the actual size in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, printing

Here's a frustrating problem.

I'm using the `UIPrintInteractionController` to print a PDF file. This PDF file's size is **A4, 595x842** in pt, but it came out that the content printed was scaled down.

The results even are different according to whether I'm using the iPhone simulator. When I test the following code in iPhone simulator, the file I printed is in its actual size. But when I test these code in the device (iPad), the problem happened and came with a log  "**Deskjet\0323520\032series\032[5B73DB]._ipp._tcp.local.: Print-Job request successful with warning: Job attributes did not match print document.**"

The code I've written is like this:

```
- (IBAction)printButtonTouched:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSURL *testFileURL = [self makeTestPDF];
    if ([UIPrintInteractionController canPrintURL:testFileURL]) {
        UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
        printInfo.jobName = testFileURL.path;
        printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationPortrait;
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
        printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexNone;

        self.myPrinter.printInfo =printInfo;
        self.myPrinter.printingItem = testFileURL;

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            [self.myPrinter presentFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {

            }];
        } else {
            [self.myPrinter presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {

            }];
        }
    }
}

- (UIPrintPaper *)printInteractionController:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController choosePaper:(NSArray *)paperList
{
    CGRect mediaBox = CGRectMake(0, 0, 595.276, 841.89);
    UIPrintPaper *bestPaper = [UIPrintPaper bestPaperForPageSize:mediaBox.size withPapersFromArray:paperList];
    return bestPaper;
}
```

When I begin a PDF page in PDF context, my code is like this:

```
    CGFloat a4Width = 595.276f;
    CGFloat a4Height = 841.89f;
    CGRect mediaBox = CGRectMake(0, 0, a4Width, a4Height);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(testPDFURL.path, mediaBox, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(mediaBox, nil);
```

The printer I'm testing on is **HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 3525**.
The same thing still happened when I test on another printer that also supports **AirPrint**, the only difference is the scaling down ratio.

I'm looking for the answer how to make the PDF printed with its actual size. And I've tried for nearly a week to find the answer, but I found no useful information. Please help me.

Comment: I am also getting same problem. Were you able to get it done?

Comment: Hey did you figure this out? having the same issue now.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar thing, but in my case I print `UIImage`. I implemented a `UIPrintPageRender` subclass and I overrided the `drawContentForPage` method. The method exposes the `CGRect` where the content should be printed:

```
class ExtendedPageRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer {
       override func drawContentForPage(at pageIndex: Int, in contentRect: CGRect) {
      // code that will draw/render in CGRect
    }
}
```

and I use the class like this:

```
let pageRenderer = ExtendedPageRenderer()
let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
printController.printPageRenderer = pageRenderer
```